# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'router'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-urls

Hi  i am getting this error please help me.
i am new on this field and i am getting this error.

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',

    'first',
]
```

my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
from .serializers import MovieSerializer,RatingSerializers
from .models import Movie,Rating
# Create your views here.
class MovieViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset=Movie.objects.all()
    serializer_class=(MovieSerializer,)
class RatingViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset=Rating.objects.all()
    serializer_class=(RatingSerializers,)
```

my main urls.py is

```
"""rest_project URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('my_apis',include('first.urls')),
]
```

and serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Movie,Rating
class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model= Movie
        fields=['title','description']

class RatingSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class meta:
        model=Rating
        fields='__all__'
```

models.py is

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator,MaxValueValidator
# Create your models here.
class Movie(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description =models.TextField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Rating(models.Model):
    movie=models.ForeignKey(Movie,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rating=models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1),MaxValueValidator(5)])
    class Meta:
        unique_together=(('user','movie'))
        index_together=(('user','movie'))
```

my urls.py (application)

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include
from rest_framework import routers
from .views import ModelViewSet,RatingViewSet

router=routers.DefaultRouter()

router.register('movies',ModelViewSet,basename='Movie')
router.register('rating',RatingViewSet,basename='Rating')

app_name='first'

urlpatterns = [
    path('',include('router.urls')),
]
```

i am following a video tutorial

and getting that error

```
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'router'
```

**please help me**
ignore that this text is to avoid "it's look like post is mostly code,please add something "

Answer (score 1):

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',include('router.urls')),
]
```

should be:

```
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

The include expression goes looking for a router module.

Comment: thank ,how can i learn that can you share a link ,because in video tutorial he use above mentioned style but it gives error .thank you for help. i don't have words for say thanks .

Comment: now it is giving AssertionError at /my_apis/movies/
'ModelViewSet' should either include a `queryset` attribute, or override the `get_queryset()` method.

Comment: That's another question and another issue. Related to the tutorial, I don't know it so can't say anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
path('', include(router.urls))
```

without **quotes**

Comment: Welcome to SO. For the next time, please spend a minute to see how to properly format your code, where bold and italics have no place (done it for you here).